# Is a neurostimulation implant for the soft-palate component of obstructive sleep apnea plausible?

Tags: biotechnology, medicine

There are currently ongoing clinical trials for neurostimulation implants designed to keep the tongue from blocking the airway in obstructive sleep apnea.  The nerves for this are in the neck and surgically accessible.

Where are the nerves that control the soft-palate, and would it be plausible to implant a similar device for them (given years of development obviously)?